# successfully installed action_mailer_optional_tls to send using GMail?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gmail, ssl

I installed action_mailer_optional_tls for Rails 2.3.2 and Ruby 1.8.6 and I cannot get ActionMailer to send email!

I get the following error:

> 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS
>   command first

Sadness...anyone had success?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is in your environment.rb file to configure the tls settings? This is what I'm using:

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = { 
  :tls => true,
  :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port => "587",
  :domain => "mydomain.com", 
  :user_name => "user@mydomain.com", 
  :password => "mypassword", 
  :authentication => :login
}
```

I've had no problems using that gem in my application running under rails 2.3.2

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem with Rails 2.3.2 and Ruby 1.8.6.  The new version of Rails uses part of Ruby 1.8.7 for TLS support.  I found out more at this [blog post](http://www.justinball.com/2009/06/25/sending-email-with-ruby-on-rails-2-3-2-and-gmail/).  Basically if you have Ruby 1.8.6 you will need to install and configure the [ActionMailerTLS](http://github.com/openrain/action_mailer_tls/tree/master) gem, you can find it on github.  My problems cleared up once I did that.